# Apple-link drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I'm looking to create a menu like seen here on the sidebar (http://help.apple.com/mobileme/) that will contain articles for a help application I'm putting together for a webapp. I'm wanting to use mostly css and jquery for the sliding like effect etc. Is there anything out-there that is similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar on that site is using something known as a ["tree view"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_view).

The Google favorite for ["jquery treeview"](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+treeview) is this:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

"Sample 3" on the [demos page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) looks like exactly what you want.